# get item by id and map it's title to string with automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I have 2 models:

```
public class Client
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    ...

    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public Guid CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Country
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to display this VM:

```
public class ClientDetailsDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    ...

    public string Country { get; set; } // Country's title
}
```

How I should get Country and map it to string Country in ClientDetailsDto?

I'm using AutoMapper in my Startup class (Startup.cs):

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<Entities.Client, Models.ClientDetailsDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
            $"{src.LastName} {src.FirstName} {src.Patronym}"))
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
            src.Birthdate.GetCurrentAge()))
        // How to get Country's title and map it to ClientDetailsDto.Country?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try like this;

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
 src.Country.Title)
```

Complete map looks like;

```
config.CreateMap<Entities.Client, Models.ClientDetailsDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        $"{src.LastName} {src.FirstName} {src.Patronym}"))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Age, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        src.Birthdate.GetCurrentAge()))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opt => opt.MapFrom(src =>
        src.Country.Title));
```

Comment: It's my first try to solve my problem, before posting :C and it's not working

Comment: So, what was the problem ?

Comment: it's returning null.

Comment: I think, the problem is not relevant with Automapper. You should provide the Linq to entity query and mapping place.

Comment: oh, I forgot to pull out the data from the DB and assign it to the client's Country attribute. Yes, you're right that the problem is not relevant with AutoMapper. Thank you.